# Background Worker for parameterized method

Tags: c#

How to add a background worker for the following method in C#.

```
public bool fileMove(string file,string destinationPath)
{

}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider elaborating on your question. It's not very clear.

That said, making the assumption that what you mean to ask is how to run your `filemove(string, string)` method as the entry point for the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event, you have a couple of options.

My preference is to provide an anonymous method as the actual event handler, and to take advantage of variable capturing to provide the actual parameters. For example:

```
void StartBackgroundWorker(string file, string destinationPath)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => filemove(file, destinationPath);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

In this way, the `BackgroundWorker` gets an event handler that matches the needed signature, and you can still call your method without changing its signature.

If for some reason you need access to the `BackgroundWorker` object in your method, then you *will* have to change the method's signature, so that the reference can be passed. But you can still mix that with the above approach:

```
void StartBackgroundWorker(string file, string destinationPath)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += (sender, e) => filemove(file, destinationPath, bw);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

If you want to avoid variable capturing altogether (but why?), it can still be done. But in that case you will need to pass the needed values to the `RunWorkerAsync()` method. For example:

```
void StartBackgroundWorker(string file, string destinationPath)
{
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

    bw.DoWork += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Tuple<string, string> args = (Tuple<string, string>)e.Argument;

        filemove(args.Item1, args.Item2);
    };
    bw.RunWorkerAsync(Tuple.Create(file, destinationPath));
}
```

And of course, you can use a `Tuple<string, string, BackgroundWorker>` in the above to pass the `BackgroundWorker` object reference if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Backgroun worker works as following, I hope it will be helpful. Try if it suits your needs:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

worker_DoWork is as following:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Write your logic here. For example call your method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method as event handler for background worker but you still have to call it using worker.RunWorkerAsyn();

```
 worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((s, ex) => filemove(file,destination));
```

calling it like ordinary method will run it on the same thread